# Monotone Testing, and Alternating Series Test of $\sum_\limits{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

> $$\sum_\limits{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}}$$

I have to use the alternating series test, and was stuck on this showing that the the function is decreasing.  For that I decided to use the monotone test of the ratio of successive terms.

> $$a_k=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\}_{k=1}^\infty$$

Using the ratio successive of terms method I get the following:
$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}}$$

My question is that if from this ratio I get that the term is $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\lt1$. Meaning that the term is strictly decreasing right? Also if I tried this method would it be valid as well, the method being the difference of successive terms.

> $$a_{k+1}-a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\frac{\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k^2+k}}$$

Which I later determined to be $a_{k+1}-a_k\lt0$, also meaning that its strictly decreasing, which then furthered me to try the differentiating of $a_k$:

> $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
> $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\lt0$$

### My Question

Since I did not want to post too many times about the monotone tests, I condensed and used them all. My question is that if I used them correctly? Don't worry about the sum I know it converges by the Alternating Series Test. I am mainly focused on the usage of the monotone tests to see if a sequence is strictly decreasing.

Comment: All methods make sense.

Comment: What about $\sqrt k<\sqrt{k+1}$ implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$?