# Wolfram Versus My Answer over the Interval of Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was given the summation:

> $$\sum_\limits{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{\sqrt{k}}$$

I got the interval of convergence of:
$$\lvert x\rvert\lt1$$
Then I broke it down to the following:
$$-1\lt x\lt 1$$
Then I had to test the end points

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interval%20of%20convergence&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22interval%20of%20convergence%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SumConvergence%22%2C%20%22sumconvergencefunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28-1%29%5E%28k-1%29x%5Ek%2Fsqrt%28k%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SumConvergence%22%2C%20%22sumconvergencevariable%22%7D%20-%3E%22k%22) says that the right endpoint is not convergent, when by using that website I proved that the following summation converges:

> $$\sum_\limits{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\sqrt{k}}$$

I even asked it in this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553316/monotone-testing-and-alternating-series-test-of-sum-limitsk-1-infty-frac) cause I did the work there. So is wolfram right or I am?

Comment: Yes, it's convergent for $x=1$ and divergent for $x=-1$. Maybe WolframAlpha didn't test the endpoints with the command you've given to it.

Comment: In fact, for $x=1$, it is $\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx 0.6049$

Comment: For $x=1$ it converges using the Leibniz Criterion. For $x=-1$ it diverges comparing it to the harmonic series.